# how to resize my modal's screen when keyboard pops up?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I was working on next.js app an there is a modal for chat. Im encountering a problem when the input field is on focus I want to rezise my modal height be half so that the keyboard popup doesn't hide the input field.

I tried to manipulate the dom but nothing changes here is the code i tries:

```
const [modalElements, setModalElements] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('modalcontent');
      setModalElements(Array.from(elements));
    }
  }, []);
 
    
  
  const handleInputFocus = () => {
    setInputFocused(true);
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
      console.log("hello input");
      modalElements.forEach((element) => {
        element.style.height = "55%";
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please also share the divs code .So you can getr specific and quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use react state:

```
import { useState } from React;

const Item = () => {

const [height, setHeight] = useState('100%'); 
const [modalElements, setModalElements] = useState([]);


const ResiseHeight = () => { setHeight('55%')}
const HandleBlure = () => { setHeight('100%')}

useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {
      const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('modalcontent');
      setModalElements(Array.from(elements));
    }
}, []);

return (
<><input onFocus={ResiseHeight } /></>
)

}
 
export default Item;
```

**Then you can use height in Modal**